# How to fetch data with multiple requests in Redux action creator and then send collected data to reducer?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, middleware

I'm using twich api to grab some basic channel informations and check if channel in question is streaming.

I have to make two separte requests to collect this data.

I wanted to make this with axios like this:

```js
export function fetchUser(user_id) {
  const get_user = `${ROOT_URL}/users/${user_id}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}`;
  const get_stream = `${ROOT_URL}/streams/${user_id}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}`;

  function getUserInfo() {
    return axios.get(get_user);
  }

  function getUserStream() {
    return axios.get(get_stream);
  }

  axios.all([getUserInfo(), getUserStream()])
    .then(axios.spread(function (infos, streams) {
      //WHAT TO DO HERE?
    }));

  return {
    type: FETCH_USER,
    payload: req,
  };
}
```

The problem is that redux-promis-middleware is tranforming only a one single Promise obj to plain obj for reducer, co I can't send array with two promises as payload.

How can I tweak this code to send both request results to reducer to update my state as plain obj instead of promise obj? Mybe somehow with redux-thunk?
I want to note that I am totally new in this matter so I would like to ask for indulgence :)

Answer (score 1):

Good news is that you can set anything in payload (including an object). So this would be handy:

```
return {
    type: FETCH_USER,//change constant here with appropriate action type
    payload: {infos:infos,streams:streams}
};
```